# Are all css animations that come in from the right bugged?

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

I wish to have a design in which three elements are supposed to come into view via different css animations whenever the user scrolls over them: one from the top, one from the left, and one from the right. However, I've since discovered that all css animations that come in from the right and  play on scroll event like this (at least using jQuery to capture it) are bugged. **The bug is that when you drag the scrollbar with the mouse it will jump back and get stuck from where you started when the animation finishes.**

This bug does not occur when you animate from the left, top, or bottom.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p88Lra7s/) to demonstrate with the following code:

HTML:

```
<div class="effect animated fadeInRight">
  <h3>Header</h3>
  <p style="text-align:justify">At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum.At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum.</p>
</div>
```

CSS (animation):

```
.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
   -webkit-transform: none;
   -ms-transform: none;
   transform: none;
  }
}

.fadeInRight {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInRight;
  animation-name: fadeInRight;
}
```

jQuery:

```
function isElementInViewport(elem) {
  var $elem = $(elem);
  var scrollElem = ((navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('webkit') != -1) ? 'body' : 'html');
  var viewportTop = $(scrollElem).scrollTop();
  var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();
  var elemTop = Math.round( $elem.offset().top );
  var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();

  return ((elemTop < viewportBottom) && (elemBottom > viewportTop));
}

function checkAnimation() {
  var $elem = $('.effect');

  if (isElementInViewport($elem)) {
    // Start the animation
    $elem.addClass('fadeInRight');
  } else {
    $elem.removeClass('fadeInRight');
  }
}

$(window).scroll(function(){
  checkAnimation();
});
```

What I want to know is if this is a general bug or just something I've done wrong, and in any case how to get around it. I've confirmed it using different browsers on different computers. I've also tried with different animations that come in from the right, but it's still the same.

Can anyone help?

Comment: If its still the same in all browser.. Possibly you have done something wrong and it isnt a bug.. Bug should have occurred in a specific browser..

Comment: Agreed, its very unlikely that there is a bug cross browsers, so it will most definitely be a problem with your code.

Comment: Well, the behavior is bug-like and I'm asking if it's something general or if I did something wrong. I don't share your definition of bugs being browser-specific only. Isn't it a bug when fadeinLeft works perfectly and fadeinRight doesn't, regardless of how many browsers it occurs in? I think so.

Comment: Can't repro on FF 36 and Safari, can repro on Webkit Mac10.9 (opera+Chrome) (It's merely a bug)

Comment: @LyndonJohnson By all means there could very well be a bug across multiple browsers. I was just saying its unlikely. I will have a little look at this. Works fine on Windows 8.1 Chrome but I see the glitch happen on my Mac Chrome. And works fine on IE Windows 8.1.

Comment: Ah, bad luck then that the only browsers I had access to were those that reproduced the bug. Still, I'd love a work-around somehow. :)

Comment: your right animation is causing a lot of extra body width thus the horizontal scroll bar. Some css to contain the page will fix it

Comment: @charlietfl It's wrapped inside a Bootstrap `container-fluid` and `row` on my real page and it's still the same. Any idea what I need to contain it?

Comment: contain the overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to charlietfl and some experimenting for this simple solution:

Wrap the whole thing in a div (in my case I use `container` from Bootstrap) and style it like this:

```
.container {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

That should fix the problem of the animation adding width to the page and therefore glitching things out.

[Here's the fixed fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/p88Lra7s/1/)